# Get all text inside one tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What is the way to get the text for d2 and d3 in the following case:

```
import bs4

htmldoc = '''<html>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def<sup>2</sup></div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc <!-- -->def3</div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div>
</html>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')
d1 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def1').findNext('div').text
print(d1)
d2 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def2').findNext('div').text
print(d2)
d3 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def3').findNext('div').text
print(d3)
```

It works only for d1, but for d2 and d3 there is an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your matching rule with text is not working with text

My solution seems like a workaround but anyway, you can try this.

You should before remove unused tags and comments using `unwrap` and `extract` methods

```
import bs4

htmldoc = '''<html>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def<sup>2</sup></div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc <!-- -->def3</div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div>
</html>'''


def get_new_soup():
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')
    divs_b = soup.find_all('div',{'class','b'})
    for div in divs_b:
        # Remove unwanted tag (like <sup> here)
        if div.sup:
            div.sup.unwrap()
        # Remove comments
        for element in div(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)):
            element.extract()

    soup_str = str(soup)
    return(bs4.BeautifulSoup(soup_str,'html.parser'))

soup = get_new_soup()

d1 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def1').findNext('div').text
print(d1)
d2 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def2').findNext('div').text
print(d2)
d3 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def3').findNext('div').text
print(d3)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
123
456
789
```

**EDIT:**

As requested in the comment, the only way I see to get your data is the following:

```
import bs4

htmldoc = '''<html>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def1</div>
    <div class="c">123</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc def<sup>2</sup></div>
    <div class="c">456</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">abc <!-- -->def3</div>
    <div class="c">789</div>
</div>
</html>'''


def get_new_soup():
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')
    divs_b = soup.find_all('div',{'class','b'})
    for div in divs_b:
        # Remove comments
        for element in div(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)):
            element.extract()

    soup_str = str(soup)
    return(bs4.BeautifulSoup(soup_str,'html.parser'))

soup = get_new_soup()

search_text = ['abc def1', 'abc def<sup>2</sup>', 'abc def3']

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'b')
for div in divs:
    content = ''.join(str(c) for c in div.contents)
    if content in search_text:
        print(div.findNext('div').text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
123
456
789
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this: `d2 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'b', text = 'abc def<sup>2</sup>').findNext('div').text`

Comment: You can check my edit. You can concat the first loop inside `get_new_soup` and the second I you like

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but doing this:

```
d1 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'c')
for i in (d1):
   print(i.text)
```

Gives this output:

```
123
456
789
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I need values for d1, d2, and d3, but the order is not constant. So I need to look inside the text of the previous tag.